# What's the correct URL root for Restful api to Neo4j Desktop?

Tags: neo4j

```
URL='http://localhost:7474/db/data'

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {
  "statements" : [
      {
        "statement" : "MATCH (n:product) RETURN n"
      } ]
}

r = requests.post(URL, headers = headers,json=data)
data = r.json()['results'][0]['data']
print(data)
```

I installed Neo4j Desktop on my local computer and created a database named 'testDB'. I can look at it in the browser, but can't the results out from API as above. The error message is:

```
data = r.json()['results'][0]['data']
KeyError: 'results'
```

When I run this alone:

```
URL='http://localhost:7474'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    print(r.json())
```

The display is below, which is different from the documentation:

```
{'data': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/', 
 'management': 'http://localhost:7474/db/manage/', 
 'bolt': 'bolt://localhost:7687'
}
```

According to the documentation, the output should be:

```
{
  "bolt_direct": "bolt://localhost:7687",
  "bolt_routing": "neo4j://localhost:7687",
  "cluster": "http://localhost:7687/db/{databaseName}/cluster",
  "transaction": "http://localhost:7687/db/{databaseName}/tx",
  "neo4j_version": "4.0.0",
  "neo4j_edition": "enterprise"
}
```

What's the correct URL to get the results out? I suspect in the URL I give, I didn't specify the 'testDB'. I may need to do some settings. What's the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options, depending on if you're using Neo4j 4.0+ - in all cases you'll need to send an Authorization header with [a valid basic authentication string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).

### `/db/data/transaction/commit` endpoint

This is [the newer HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/actions/), where you can run multiple statements - don't worry that it says 'transaction' and 'commit' in the URL, you can also just use it for querying:

```
{
  "statements" : [
      {
        "statement" : "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25"
      } 
  ]
}
```

If you're on Neo4j 4.0.0 this will target whatever is configured as the 'default' database.

### `/db/{databasename}/tx/commit` endpoint

e.g. `/db/testdb/tx/commit`

Introduced in 4.0 is multi-database support on one running server. The query format is the same, but `transaction` has become `tx` in the URL and `data` becomes the name of your database.

```
{
  "statements" : [
      {
        "statement" : "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25"
      } 
  ]
}
```

Note: multi database support **is not** the same as simply creating multiple graphs in Desktop. Desktop is still only ever running one database server, but if you make that server a Neo4j 4.0.0+ instance you can host multiple databases within it and switch between them at query-time.

### `/db/data/cypher` endpoint

[This is deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-cypher), but still works for versions < 4.0.0:

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (x) RETURN x LIMIT 25"
}
```

You can find more information about the query format in each case from the linked docs.

Comment: So I don't need to specify the database name, 'testDB'. What about if I have multiple db creations?

Comment: Added some clarification - if you're using Neo4j 4.0+ and you've created multiple database under the same server, then the URL needs to include the database name (otherwise you'll just be hitting the 'default' database. Don't confuse that with Neo4j Desktop's notion of a graph though - you're only ever running one server at a time with Desktop, so unless you're using the new `CREATE DATABASE` statement to create a new database within a server, you probably want the first option.